# How do you disable html div elements (input fields, textareas etc) using jQuery in Smalltalk?

Tags: jquery, smalltalk, seaside

I'm new to Smalltalk and needed some help. I'm essentially trying to accomplish the following but in a Smalltalk setting:

```
$("#divId :input").attr("disabled", true);
```

I've tried hiding the div using the following which works fine:
(html jQuery id: 'divId') hide.

But I want to disable the elements within the div instead, i.e., make the div read-only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You don't necessarily need to use an id to select DOM nodes from Seaside.
You can also do this:

```
(html jQuery: '#divId input') propertyAt: 'disabled' put: true.
```

Comment: Would this extend to the children of the div? #divId is a container of sorts, which encloses other input fields, buttons. The above doesn't seem to work for these.

Comment: I don't understand your question. This css selector says: select me all input elements that are inside an element that has the id #divId. Nothing more, nothing less. Show us the html code of your div and we can probably find the cause of your problems.